# Android lockscreen that allows quick access when connected to specific WiFi networks

Tags: android, wifi, lockscreen, android-nougat

Please recommend an Android lockscreen that does not require any swiping/pin/password entry when the device is connected to one or more user-specified WiFi networks.

Must be compatible with non-rooted Android Nougat.

Any price is fine.

Comment: Hm? Why do you want a specific app for something that's built-in? That's called [Smart Unlock](https://support.google.com/nexus/answer/6093922). Strange that help page doesn't mention WiFi (only Bluetooth). If that's true, maybe one of [these apps](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_wifi_automation#group_435) (my list, as usual) might do the trick. Unfortunately either paid or root – but you wrote "any price is fine", so [Smart Unlock](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.loadinghome.smartunlock) might be a candidate ;)

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  I'm not seeing Smart Unlock anywhere in the Settings UI in Nougat.  Maybe some OEM ROM's don't include it.

Comment: Strange. But if it really doesn't include WiFi, you'll have to revert to an app-based solution anyway. Did the *Smart Unlock* app I've linked fit your needs?

Comment: @Izzy Thanks.  There are  2 links to *Smart Unlock*, and I looked at the first one, thinking the second one was a duplicate link.  I didn't realize the links are for 2 different things, but with the same name. I'll check out the app!  Thanks again.

Comment: Thought so – hence the reminder :) Confusing, yeah – but that app obviously wants to fill the gap that shouldn't be there, and thus named itself such ;)